# Padding at the bottom is bigger?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone tell me, please, why underneath the last image in my content area, is their a bigger space than their is between the image at the top? I have padding set to 10px and I can't see what is doing it, below is my code in brackets I have highlighted what I mean, thanks for any help as this is driving me mad.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title here</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    body,html {
     font-family:Franklin Gothic Book;
     size:11px;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     color:#030303;
     background:#FFF;
     vertical-align:top;
   }
   td {
    vertical-align:top;
   }
   #wrap {
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: url("layout_background.png") repeat-y;
    overflow: hidden
  }
  #header {
    width:100%;
    background:#333;
    padding:0;
  }
  .center {
    text-align:center;
  }
  .header {
    width:100%;
    padding:0;
    min-height:160px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#CDCDCD', endColorstr='#9C9C9C');
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#CDCDCD), to(#9C9C9C)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #CDCDCD,  #9C9C9C);
    border-top:1px solid #303030;
    border-bottom:1px solid #303030;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
#nav {
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:#030303;
    border-top:1px solid #303030;
    text-align:right;
}
#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
p {
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding-right:10px;
    background-color:#030303;
}
#main {
    float:left;
    width:689px;
    padding:10px;
}
h2 {
    margin:0 0 1em;
}
#sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:250px;
    padding:10px;
    border-left:1px solid #303030;
}
    a:link {
    color: #236B8E;
}
    a:active {
    color: #236B8E;
}
    a:visited {
    color: #236B8E;
}
    a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
#footer {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    border-top:1px solid #303030;
    line-height:20px;
}
#footer p {
    padding-left:10px;
    margin:0;
}
* html #footer {
    height:1px;
}
    </style>
        </head>

         <body>

<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Application</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="/">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Roster</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Champions</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Boards</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Affiliates</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="header">
    <div class="center"><img src="logo.png"></div>
</div>

    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
        <img src="test.png" width="689" height="120">
        <p>
        <img src="test.png" width="689" height="120">
        <p>
        <img src="test.png" width="689" height="120">
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    updates
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer"><p>Copyright here</p>              </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE: http://postimg.org/image/cv8yuzak1/

Comment: You have padding set for both the image and the div following it. Could that be it?

Comment: No, I don't have any padding set for the images or any classes for the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you have to add margin-top to the main and add img tag. Also the you have to remove the unclosed `p` tag

```
#main img {
    float:left;
    width:689px;
   /* padding:10px;*/
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#footer {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:14px;
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    border-top:1px solid #303030;
    line-height:20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
```

http://jsbin.com/geguhiba/2/

Comment: The gap is still larger at the top?

Comment: Please take a screenshot for the demo and upload it to image share after highlighting the area you mean. or update your question with the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I have updated and added a link to the photo: http://postimg.org/image/cv8yuzak1/

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I am just getting into designing so it's confusing to me but I will get their.. lol, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the issue in the jsfiddle I created with the code you provided. It looks like the

```
padding:10px
```

is working fine to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/zLLcC/

Comment: Yeah it is working, but the gap between the footer and the last image I have in my content area is slightly bigger than the gap between the header and the image I have at the top of my content?

Comment: It's because the last two images are inside of <p> tags (without closing tags) but your first image is by itself

Answer (score 0):

```
#main img {
float:left;
width:689px;
padding:10px;
}
```

set padding to images not the div

Comment: If I do this then all other content around/above/under the images won't have any padding?

Comment: yeah right and if u want other content gets padding drag img and others to a <li> so do this #main li { padding : 10px }

Answer (score 0):

use margins and paddings instead of tag p. or you can specify it's margin manually. by default it's 17px or 16px. look at this http://jsbin.com/kubimaro/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it is exactly right when I click on your page, but I copied exactly what you done in a separate file and saved it. When I view it it's exactly how it was before again?? I'm so confused..